# Update with join takes 9 to 30 hours for some reason?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, lets called them table_A and table_B.  Table_A has about 10 million rows. Table_B has 300 million rows. I created indexes on Table_B columns X and Y.

Is it normal that the updates would take this long with the number of rows I have ? This seems extremely long to me considering I have an index

Here is what they look like

Table A:

```
ID   BCODE 
1    A1 
2    B1  
3    C1  
4    D1  
5    F1
```

Table B:

```
X    Y    IDX  IDY
A1   D1  
D1   F1  
C1   B1
```

Table_B has columns 'X' and 'Y' that have values that are found in Table_A's column BCODE.

I run two update statements that take 9 to 30 hours to complete.

```
 Update Table_B
join table_A a on table_B.X = a.BCODE
set
   table_B.IDX=a.Id ;

Update Table_B
join Table_A aa on table_B.Y = aa.BCODE
set
   table_B.IDY = aa.Id  ;
```

Is there anyway I can speed this up ? I should add that the BCODE, X, Y columns can be up to 300 characters long

Here are the results of Explain:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key         | key_len |  ref         | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a         | ALL  | BCODE         | NULL        | NULL    | NULL         | 10238784 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table_B   | ref  | relateIndex   | relateIndex | 632     | test.a.BCODE |       15 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+------------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: whats the execution/explain plan look like? even with indices you're still updating hundreds of millions of rows so memory / processor / disk access is going to be a factor

Comment: Is table_B.X and aa.BCODE having the same datatype ? Is aa.BCODE is also indexed ?

Comment: I added the explain results. Both tables have the same datatype for the joined columns

Comment: also try enabling profiling, and then profiling that update query when you run it (note it'll have to run the full length of time). if you have the time to spare, this will show you how your query is spending its time.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html

Comment: Approximately how many rows are in each table? Approximately how many rows in table B have a match for every value of bcode in table A?

Comment: table_B has  350205473 rows. Table_A has 10238784 rows. Every row in table_B should have a match in table_A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [*covering* index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Covering_index):

```
create index table_a_bcode_id on table_A(bcode, id);
```

Covering indexes provide the looked up value(s) *in* the index, avoiding access to the table - making an index-only query possible.

Your queries look OK, but try combining them:

```
update Table_B
left join table_A a1 on a1.BCODE = table_B.X
left join table_A a2 on a2.BCODE = table_B.Y
set table_B.IDX = a1.Id
    table_B.IDY = a2.Id
```

This avoids having to update the row twice.

Comment: I originally did have the update combined into one statement, but the problem was that  If one of the columns failed to match on the join then the other , even if it matches wont be written to the update.  I will try the covering index though and let you know

Comment: @aries addressing the no-join is easy (see edit), but tell me if there's no join, is it ok to write a null to idX or idY? If so, current query will work. If not, let me know.

Comment: It took 5 hours to create the covered index & 3.5 hrs to do the update left join but it finally finished at least. Thanks Bohemian, you rock !

Answer (score 2):

From the EXPLAIN output, it looks like Table_A.BCODE does not have an index on BCODE. If you want to do a JOIN, both tables should be indexed on the JOIN fields, otherwise the non-indexed table will slow things down because of the O(N) complexity of lookups.

Apart from that, you have mentioned that both columns are strings up to 300 characters long. Indices on such columns are not very effective. If you could find a way to hash the values in these columns and then perform join by hashed values, it could speed things up.

On the other side, with tables that large, you should check if the indices even fit into memory. If they don't, then MySQL will start swapping your index to disk, which would tremendously slow things down.

We can do an estimation: 600 (your index key length) x 300M (number of rows) = 200 GB... So quite likely this is the issue.

Possible workaround: try partitioning your table_B (e.g.by PK) so that for every part the index could fit into memory (it could mean 25 partitions or more, assuming your MySQL instance could use up to 8 GB RAM).

Comment: I did add an index to table_A after I posted the EXPLAIN, but its been 5 hours after the index was created, and the update is still running. So maybe youre right about the indices not fitting in memory. I will lookup how to do partitioning. Thank you  !